# JobSchedule Android

Tags: android

Привет, ребята, помогите мне, пожалуйста. Ситуация такая: изучаю я сейчас `JobSchedule`. Один и тот же проект на одном компе всё работает, и в эмуляторе и через шнур, на другом этот же проект, не работает, ни на эмуляторе, ни черз шнур - на том же телефоне. Почему так? Вот сам проект. Он тривиален - две кнопки - одна создает задачу, другая ее отменяет. Не знаю, что теперь и делать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Студию переустанавливал. Настройки сбрасывал. Кеш в телефоне чистил. 
Код на гитхабе не менялся
https://github.com/Denchabaev/JobSchedulerDemo

Comment: Что значит проект не работает на компе? Какие ошибки, где?